# App throwing "Unsupported MGF1 digest: SHA-256. Only SHA-1 supported" although I use recommended approach

Tags: android, cryptography

In my android app I want to store secret keys in android key store. But My App throws `java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Unsupported MGF1 digest: SHA-256. Only SHA-1 supported` when I use `AndroidKeyStoreRSAPrivateKey` in Cipher initialization:

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(RSA, "AndroidKeyStore");
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
                end.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
                KeyPairGeneratorSpec spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(context)
                        .setAlias(ALIAS)
                        .setKeyType(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA)
                        .setAlgorithmParameterSpec(new RSAKeyGenParameterSpec(2048, F4))
                        .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=" + ALIAS))
                        .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(Math.abs(ALIAS.hashCode())))
                        .setStartDate(start.getTime())
                        .setEndDate(end.getTime())
                        .build();
                try {
                    kpg.initialize(spec);
                } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
            publicKey = kp.getPublic();
            privateKey = kp.getPrivate();

            //......................

            // creating and initalizing Cipher

            final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding");

            // in this place exception is thrown
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,
                    key,
                    new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256,
                    PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT));
```

Exception is thrown in `cipher.init()`. But when my private key is instance of `OpenSSLRSAPrivateKey` generated by `KeyFactory.getInstance(RSA)`  issue is not reproduced and all works fine, excepting that I need exactly AndroidKeyStoreRSAPrivateKey. I read developer doc https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/cryptography , but it doesn't contain any info regarding to my problem.
How should I change the code to solve the issue?

Comment: At which exact line in the presented code the was Exception thrown? Please edit your question and add this info.

Comment: Well, if it isn't supported then it isn't supported by the Android provider. And you probably cannot convert to the OpenSSL key and use the OpenSSL provider because - well - the private key is still protected by the key store. Note that MGF1 with SHA-1 is still considered secure (although I can imagine that is of little help if you need compatiblity or if you want to move away from SHA-1 altogether). You could try a newer Android API, perhaps.

Comment: @Robert exception was thrown in `cipher.init()`